# Can't get android 7 on galaxy s6

Tags: android-versions

I have tried manually updating my galaxy s6 but it says I have the latest (6.0.1) but I know this isn't true! My friend has practically the same phone but with android 7. How do I update mine?

This is a screenshot of the manual update:
[image: as you can see these are the codes for marshmallow]

Comment: Is it unlocked?  That is the first step if you are doing this manually

Comment: Its unlocked yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updates are always rolled out in batches to different regions (even the same exact  model could be sold around the world). For your region (`G920FBTU5DQA2` - `BTU` - United Kingdom), as [SamMobile](https://www.sammobile.com/firmwares/galaxy-s6/SM-G920F/) states, 6.0.1 is indeed the latest.

You could always manually flash firmware for the same model but for another region (listed on the same page) via Odin, at the cost of potentially losing your data (back up first) as well as certain region-specific optimizations.

Comment: Okay. Is there a way of finding out when the update will come to my model?

Comment: None that I know of.